# Cbind a dataframe and output using paste to create labels

Tags: r, string, label, paste, cbind

I'm trying to cbind a dataset while also creating a label and I can't get it to work.

My current attempt is:

```
 for (i in c(5,10,15)){
   or (g in c(1,2,3,4)){

     if (i==5) {data1 <- df[,6:10]}
     if (i==10) {data1 <- df[,6:15]}
     if (i==15) {data1 <- df[,6:20]}

     model1 <- Mclust(data=data1, G = g, modelNames = NULL, prior = NULL)
     df <- cbind(df, paste("g",g,"_",i,sep="")=model1$loglik)

   }
 }
```

As you can see in the last line of code, I'm trying to bind the existing dataset (df) with the output of the model (model1$loglik) with the variable label (e.g., g1_5). When I run the paste function normally, it returns a string (e.g., "g1_5") but when I run it in the cbind it returns it as the code, not string it normally outputs.

Any suggestions on how to do this? If there's an alternate to paste, or another way to make the labels adaptive to the specific loop they're created in, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The `paste` on the `lhs` to create the name wouldn't work.  It may be better to assign (`[[`) or use `setNames`.  In the second line of code, there is a typo.  It could be `for(g in c(1,2,3,4))`

```
 ...
  df[[paste("g", g, "_", i, sep="")]] <- model1$loglik

  
  }
 }
```